# comparison with type of None variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

I know that comparison of types is not recommended, but I have some code that does this in an if elif series. However, I am confused as to how None values work.

```
def foo(object)
    otype = type(object)
    #if otype is None: # this doesn't work
    if object is None: # this works fine
        print("yep")
    elif otype is int:
    elif ...
```

How come I can compare just fine with `is int` and so forth, but not with `is None`? types.NoneType seems to be gone in Python 3.2, so I can't use that...

The following

```
i = 1
print(i)
print(type(i))
print(i is None)
print(type(i) is int)
```

prints

```
1
<class 'int'>
False
True
```

whereas

```
i = None
print(i)
print(type(i))
print(i is None)
print(type(i) is None)
```

prints

```
None
<class 'NoneType'>
True
False
```

I guess `None` is special, but what gives? Does `NoneType` actually exist, or is Python lying to me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`None` is a special-case singleton provided by Python.  `NoneType` is the type of the singleton object.  `type(i) is None` is `False`, but `type(i) is type(None)` should be true.

Answer (score 7):

You should never need to compare to `NoneType`, because `None` is a singleton.  If you have some object `obj` that might be `None`, just is `obj is None` or `obj is not None`.

The reason your comparison does not work is that `None` is not a type, it is a value.  It would similar to trying `type(1) is 1` in your integer example.  If you really wanted to do a `NoneType` check, you could use `type(obj) is type(None)`, or better yet `isinstance(obj, type(None))`.

Comment: Very true and important, but the other parts of the question deserve an answer too.

Comment: Which makes checking `None`-ness a special case in any type-checking code.  Sometimes, it is cleaner to check for `NoneType` than to check `x is None or isinstance(x, (footype, bartype))`.

Comment: Object identity is actually the right thing for checking for a type: `type(obj) is SomeType` is what I recommend for checking for *exact* type matches (a very rare requirement).  In the common case, use `isinstance()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Good to know!  For some reason I thought type checking called for a value comparison.